# Transfer selected web sockets to browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, browser, request

My understanding of web programming isn't the best, so I might have some misconceptions here about how it works in general, but hopefully what I'm trying to do is possible.

Recently my friend and I have been challenging each other to break web systems we've set up, and in order to break his next one I need to use the requests module, while doing part of it by myself. I'm perfectly happy with the requests module, but after a while, I want to manually take over that session with the server in my browser. I've tried `webbrowser.open`, but this effectively loads the page again as if I've never connected before, due to not having any of the cookies from the other session. Is this possible, or do I have a misunderstanding of the situation? Thanks in advance for any help.